# Reading, formatting, sorting, and saving a csv file without pandas

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I am given some sample data in a file --> transactions1.csv
[transactions1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYbH7.png)

I need to do code a function that will do the following without using pandas:

1. Open the file
2. Sort the index column in ascending order
3. Save the updated data back to the same file

This is the code I currently have

```
import csv

def sort_index():
    read_file=open("transactions1.csv","r")
    r=csv.reader(read_file)
    lines=list(r)
    sorted_lines=sorted(lines[1:], key=lambda row: row[0])
    read_file.close()
    
    with open('transactions1.csv','w',newline='') as file_writer:
        header=['Index','Day','Month','Year','Category','Amount','Notes'] #-
        writer=csv.DictWriter(file_writer, fieldnames=header)
        writer=csv.writer(file_writer)
        writer.writerows(sorted_lines)
        
    return False

sort_index()
```

Current output:

```
1,2,Dec,2021,Transport,5,MRT cost
10,19,May,2020,Transport,25,taxi fare
2,5,May,2021,investment,7,bill
3,2,Aug,2020,Bills,8,small bill
4,15,Feb,2021,Bills,40,phone bill
5,14,Oct,2021,Shopping,100,shopping 20
6,27,May,2021,Others,20,other spend
7,19,Nov,2019,Investment,1000,new invest
8,28,Mar,2020,Food,4,drink
9,18,Nov,2019,Shopping,15,clothes
```

The code doesn't seem to work because index 10 appears right after index 1. And the headers are missing.

Expected Output:

```
Index,Day,Month,Year,Category,Amount,Notes
1,2,Dec,2021,Transport,5,MRT cost
10,19,May,2020,Transport,25,taxi fare
2,5,May,2021,investment,7,bill
3,2,Aug,2020,Bills,8,small bill
4,15,Feb,2021,Bills,40,phone bill
5,14,Oct,2021,Shopping,100,shopping 20
6,27,May,2021,Others,20,other spend
7,19,Nov,2019,Investment,1000,new invest
8,28,Mar,2020,Food,4,drink
9,18,Nov,2019,Shopping,15,clothes
```

Comment: Convert it to int (`int(row[0])` instead of `row[0]`). Now you are sorting strings.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the headings to show in my output as well?

Comment: yes, call `next(r)`, also no need to convert to list

Comment: when i try next(r) , i get 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'D'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several improvements can be made to the current function.

No need to call `list` on the `reader` object, we can `sort` it directly as it is iterable.

We can extract the headers from the `reader` object by calling `next` directly on the reader object.

It is more maintainable if we define a custom key function not using `lambda`, that way if something changes only the function definition needs to change.

Use a `with` statement to automatically handle closing the file object.

```
def _key(row):
    return int(row[0])

def sort_index():
    with open("transactions1.csv", "r") as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        header = next(reader)
        rows = sorted(reader, key=_key)
    with open("transactions1.csv", "w", newline="") as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerows(rows)
```